# whats better? 20,000 mAh 5V Battery or 9Ah 18v battery to use as portable power charger?

Tags: batteries, capacity

So I bought battery brick from Amazon.ca it was a 20,000 mAh, it's a 5v battery pack. I also just bought a Milwaukee 9 Ah 18v battery for my tools and beside it I saw an adapter that let me click onto the top of the battery the ability to use it to charge my phone. I could not tell what one was better when it comes to capacity. Because one is an 18V battery and the other is 5V. How can I calculate what is a better battery to use to charge my battery if my phone requires 5V 3A to charge. If I only had room for 1 battery on a trip what one should I bring?

Update:
My phone battery is 4000 mAh so lets assume that every time i charge it I want to fill it up.. I really don't care what I am charging though but what battery listed above would last longer... therefore charge my phone more if you assume 5V 3A when charging it!

Comment: *Total energy stored* = *Ah rating* times *voltage*.

Comment: How long is the trip? How often will you recharge your phone and for how long? Why can't you use a cigar lighter in your vehicle? Which battery is lightest? Do you need to take tools with you? Are you allowed to take the adapter with you? Have you done any research on what ampere hour capacity means?

Comment: Note that neither pack is actually a battery with the listed specs; the former is a Li-ion or Lipo battery with a boost circuit, and the other is a battery with 18V *nominal* voltage but whose voltage will actually vary with time.

Comment: This is just a hypothetical question not real life, I have a cig lighter charger I was just curious how you would compare the two devices to each other, different battery types, different mAh different voltage rated for.. If a 5V 3A load was placed on both till they were dead which one would last longer.. and how would you calculate that?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks so in that case that I assume all batteries are alike ( i know they are not but for simplicity's sake) I would get 20Ah x 5V so 100 total stored for the Aukey battery pack, and 9Ah x 18V so 188 stored value. SO now that I can compare them properly I can see the Milwaukee battery pack will hold move total energy but if i am converting 18v to 5V will i loose much from that conversion process?

Comment: @SteveMain Depends on the converter. Switching DC/DC converters are quite efficient (~90%)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to specify one battery in mAh, and the other in Ah, especially when the first is a higher value than the second.  We do engineering here.  Learn to use grown-up units if you want to be taken seriously.

Comment: @OlinLathrop That's why I am asking a bunch of people that do know. These are the rating the manufactures give us then expect us to know the difference between all of them. It was just a question about how you would calculate which one would theatrically last longer if put under the same load. Sorry if I insulted my intelligence by the question. I know what I don't know and I didn't know the answer to this question hence why I asked people that did. Some were very friendly and helpful answers, yours was not one of them. Sorry if my basic question with kid units was too basic for you!

Comment: Then your question is misleading.  You talk about amp-hours and ask about something at a higher level.  That implies you understand amp-hours.  If you don't know what amp-hours are, then you need to ask about that first.  Don't use terms that you don't understand, unless that's what you're asking about.  In any case, my comment was about the milli multiplier prefix.  That applies whether you understand the unit that is being multiplied or not.  If you truly don't know what milli means, then you need to go back and learn some very basics things before coming here again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a 5V 3A load was placed on both till they were dead which one would last longer.. and how would you calculate that?

- Load power consumption:
  5 V * 3 A = 5*3 V*A = **15 W**.
- Amazon power bank energy:
  While 20 Ah (20,000 mAh = 20 Ah) at 5 V would store 5*20 V*Ah = 100 Wh of energy, I really doubt that the 20 Ah battery within really has a nominal voltage of 5 V. Most likely 5 V is the (boosted) *output voltage* of the thing, and the actual battery has a nominal voltage around 3.7 V. A 20 Ah 3.7 V battery stores 3.7*20 V*Ah = 74 Wh of energy. In Joules, that is 74 Wh * (3600 s)/(1 h) = 74*3600 Wh*s/h = 266400 Ws = 266400 J = **266.4 kJ**.
- Milwaukee tool battery energy:
  9 Ah at 18 V stores 18*9 V*Ah = 162 Wh of energy. Again, in Joules, 162 Wh * (3600 s)/(1 h) = 162*3600 Wh*s/h = 583200 J = **583.2 kJ**.

Assuming a 100 % efficient DC/DC conversion to 5 V:

- The power bank will supply the load for 266.4 kJ / 15 W = 266.4 kWs / 15 W = 17.46 kWs/W = 17.46 ks = 17460 s (slightly under 5 hours).
- The tool battery will supply the load for 583.2 kJ / 15 W = 38.33 kWs/W = 38330 s (almost 11 hours).

For a more realistic figure, multiply those estimated durations by 0.85 to account for inefficiencies in the power conversion.